# Can we write junit tests for any groovy script which does not have any class and methods? If yes then how?

Tags: groovy, junit

I have a situation where I have to write a code for a groovy script which is not written inside a class . Its just a plain groovy script. For some reason I can't show the actual code .But it would simply like this:

```
def var = 10
return var
```

Comment: https://kousenit.org/2011/02/24/testing-groovy-scripts/

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object of the class and call run() method on it. This will instantiate the class and run the method in it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to write tests specially in the case that you mentioned.

Use in-built `assert` for the same.

```
def var = 10
var++
assert 11 == var, 'Value mismatch for var'
```

Answer (score 0):

One style is to write micro-tests inline, using the `assert` feature (as mentioned elsewhere):

```
def reverseString = { s ->
    s?.reverse()
}

// test_reverseString
assert 'cba' == reverseString('abc')
assert '' == reverseString('')
assert null == reverseString(null)

def sumList = { list ->
    (list == null) ? 0 :
        (list.isEmpty()) ? 0 :
            list.sum()
}

// test_sumList
assert 6 == sumList([1,2,3])
assert 0 == sumList([])
assert 0 == sumList(null)

// ---- main

println reverseString('esrever')
println sumList([1,2,3,4])
```

It is relatively easy to modify this code so that only the tests execute (e.g. based on a command-line argument).